# Latest Security Update KB

Tags: c++, security, winapi, wuapi

I'm looking how to get programmatically the KB of latest security update, currently in use on local computer . Any tips ? I've tried some thins like wuapi but i'm not getting any results . I wanna check if the MS17-010: Security update for Windows SMB is in use .

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're looking for? There are many security updates. Do you want the very last one installed, and if so why? It's unlikely that information would be of any use.

Comment: I'm looking to check if MS17-010: Security update for Windows SMB is in use

Comment: So, that's not the same thing as looking for the "latest" security update. You're trying to query whether a particular update is installed. You could (and probably do!) have other updates installed after that one.

Comment: `check kb installed windows` on Google gives me useful information...

Comment: I'm looking to get it programmatically. I thought that an older version is installed if the current one i get as the latest is a newer version

Comment: I think you can (somehow) tell Windows not to install specific updates, so they don't have to be installed in order.

Answer (score 0):

To check a specific update programmatically, you can for example query the registry. Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages` a key with the name that contains the KB identifier should be present (eg. "`Package_for_KB111111_...`"), and under that the `CurrentState` value is decimal 112 if it is fully installed.

MS17-010 is KB4012598.

Some more info with other possible statuses and more is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tip_of_the_day/tip-of-the-day-cbs-servicing-states-chart-refresher).